# Prove a sequence is bisection of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have proven a formula for the number of configurations of n hyperplanes in an n-dimensional space:

C(n) = n(n+1)/2+1(C(n-1)-1)+2C(n-2)-1)+3(C(n-3)-1)+...+(n-2)(C(2)-1).

Much to my surprise the results form the bisection of the Fibonacci sequence. I asked on this site for a proof that this is so, received a kind and thorough response, but frankly I have trouble understanding the response. So I tried a different proof:

Let F(2n) = a(n) be the bisection of the Fibonacci sequence. Through research I found this formula: a(n) = 3a(n-1)-a(n-2). So I wrote C(n)= 3C(n-1)-C(n-2), substituted my formula for each term on the right side and got after simplification:

C(n)=n^2-1+3(C(n-2)-1)+5(C(n-3)-1)+7(C(n-4)-1)+...+(2n-5)(C(2)-1).

To prove the two formulas are the same, I subtracted the first formula from the second formula, and was able to show that for all *n* the result is zero. My question is does that prove that my original formula gives the bisection of the Fibonacci sequence? Does a(n) = 3a(n-1)-a(n-2) **if and only if** the sequence is the bisection of the Fibonacci sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly if $(a_n)$ is the bisection of the Fibonacci sequence, then $a_n=3a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$, as you discovered.

But the converse is not true, because the whole sequence depends on the first two values. If your sequence starts with $0,1$, then you will get the bisection of the Fibonacci squence. But if it starts with anything else, you won't.

(I have assumed that your Fibonacci sequence starts $F_0=0,F_1=1,F_2=1,\ldots,$ so its bisection starts with $a_0=0,a_1=1,a_2=3,\ldots$ But this is not entirely standard, so the specific starting values $0,1$ may not match your terminology. But you get the idea.)